# How can I enforce that my composite key columns do not equal one another in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-8.0, unique-constraint

I have a pivot table in which there is a composite key made up of two columns that reference the same table. The columns are `requester_id` and `addressee_id` and both of them refer to the `id` field on a `users` table. I'm trying to make sure that something like this **cannot** happen:

```
requester_id   addressee_id   created_at
1              1              2020-08-09 18:40:23
```

I've also added an *index expression* to ensure that there can only be one unique pairing of IDs as well:

```
alter table `user_relationships` 
add unique index `unique_relationships_index`
((least(requester_id,addressee_id)), (greatest(requester_id,addressee_id)))
```

To avoid having `1|2` and `2|1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL-8.0.16 enforces [check constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

```
alter table user_relationships add check (requester_id <> addressee_id)
```

Afterwards:

```
insert into user_relationships values (3,3,NOW())
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'user_relationships_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

[ref: fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=219d93e6c2032baa933e72b9400c3dfd)

Comment: I would also recommend naming the check something instructive to whomever is developing within the database to make it a little more clear what rule is being violated, e.g. `ck_users_requestor_ne_addressee`.